# How can i replace a string with a HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building an autocomplete and now i'm trying to highlight the search string in the name of the listed found results but i just don't seem to manage to even do a replace for some reason. I tried separately and it doesn't work and i don't understand why.

Here's the function that creates the result html elements:

```
jQuery( function() {

        var searchString = "";

        var categoryListElement = jQuery('#SearchResults .categories .list');
        var productListElement = jQuery('#SearchResults .products .list');

        function trimSearchResults(resultObject){
            var categories = resultObject.data.categories.slice(0,5);
            var products = resultObject.data.products.slice(0,5);

            return {'categories' : categories, 'products' : products};
        }

        function populateSearchResults(listData, targetListElement) {

            if (listData.length == 0)
                targetListElement.parent().hide();
            else
                targetListElement.parent().show();

            function createCategoryElement(categoryElementObject) {

                console.log(categoryElementObject.name);

                var nameHighlight = categoryElementObject.name;
                nameHighlight.replace(searchString, "kakakakak");

                console.log(nameHighlight);

                var element = jQuery("<li>" +
                    "<a href=" +  categoryElementObject.url + ">" +
                        "<img src='/images/" + categoryElementObject.image + "'>" +
                        "<span>" + categoryElementObject.name + "</span>" +
                    "</a>" +
                "</li>");

                return element;
            }

            targetListElement.empty();

            listData.forEach(function(item, index){
                targetListElement.append(createCategoryElement(item));
            });

        }

        jQuery("#SearchInputs input").on('input', function(){
            searchString = jQuery(this).val();

            if (searchString.length >= 2)
            {
                jQuery.get(
                    "http://www.theperfecturn.com/search?keywords=" + searchString,
                    function(response){
                        console.log(trimSearchResults(response));
                        var trimmedResults = trimSearchResults(response);
                        populateSearchResults(trimmedResults.categories, categoryListElement);
                        populateSearchResults(trimmedResults.products, productListElement);

                        jQuery("#SearchResults").show();
                    }
                );
            }
        });

        jQuery("#SearchInputs input").on('blur', function(){
            jQuery("#SearchResults").hide();
        });

} );
```

and the HTML:

```
        <div id="SearchInputsHolder" class="col-4">
            <div id="SearchInputs" class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search for...">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-standard" type="button">Go</button>
                </span>
            </div>

            <div id="SearchResults" class="hidden">

                <div class="categories">
                    <div class="header">Categories</div>
                    <ul class="list"></ul>
                    <div class="all-results-link"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="products">
                    <div class="header">Products</div>
                    <ul class="list"></ul>
                    <div class="all-results-link"></div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where does `searchString` come from? What does `categoryElementObject` look like? Do you get any errors when running this? If you could make this a complete reproducing example we'd be able to help far more easily.

Comment: Where are you replacing text with HTML? I only see a call to `nameHighlight.replace` and you don't even save that anywhere!?

Comment: post code for `categoryElementObject`

Comment: remember that `replace` returns a new string, so it must be assigned, something like: `origString = origString.replace("findMe", "insertMe");`

Comment: @radarbob - we don't know what `nameHighlight` is, you're assuming it's a string, it might not be. OP needs to opst more code.

Comment: i just added the whole code for my autocomplete, hope this clarifies what i have

Comment: @DBS check it out now

Comment: @xander it's there, take a look

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. i added the whole code, care to take a look?

Comment: @JonathanSzekely any chance you could allow CORS so we can run your code? if you could provide the html used that would be handy too.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. i edited the post and added html as well. i don't know what CORS is

Comment: what language is the back end written in?

Comment: it's PHP on Laravel 4.2. i am getting a response JSON from the server and it's all good, but i just can't seem to make that replace function work for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Where is your searchString variable declared.Because while replacing you are not giving any input string..I think you should assign the text you want to replace in the searchString  variable..Then it will work

Comment: it could be a global variable. we don't know. OP didn;t post enough code.

Comment: It's a string. The use is precisely the `String.replace()` signature. That, and the other obviously `String` functions in the function call rabbit hole plus its use in string concatenation. Whatever it "is", its value is a string.

Comment: @radarbob check the post again, i added the rest of the code

Comment: @radarbob `nameHighlight` was not concatted anywhere and there was no reason to assume it wasn't an object with a user defined property called `replace`. you shouldn't assume so much.. now that the entire code is posted we know it's a string, before it was just a baseless assumption.

Comment: I see this: `var nameHighlight = categoryElementObject.name;` Then about 4 lines later is this: ` "<span>" + categoryElementObject.name + "</span>" +`.  That's all I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign 
var something= nameHighlight.replace(searchString, "kakakakak");
when replacing the string name.
after that you can use the replaced string variable 'something' in the element binding.
This is why your replace is not working.
I think this is solve.